# Writing to a file from a C++ and reading the same file from PHP

Tags: php, c++, c, file, io

I have C++ program which writes to a file, while a PHP code can simultaneously reading from this file.

If the reading PHP process opens the file at the same time the C++ program has opened that file, can this cause some problem ?

If so, what should the best way for this kind of communication ?

I think a pipe should be always the best solution in this cases. Is it ?

Comment: Having one program writing to a file at the same time another program is reading it sounds like a really bad idea to me.  The EOF marker would keep moving for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Write to a temp file and after you're done rename/move the temp file to the original. This process ensures that you won't read 'half baked' file from your php code.